# C++ generating random numbers without repetition .output screen is just blank with a blinking cursor

Tags: c++, random

My intention is to generate random numbers from 1 to 9 without repetition

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int randrange(int low,int high)   /* generates a random number within given range*/
{
    return rand()%(low+high)+low+1;     
}

int main()
{
    int num[9]={0},i,j;     
    bool check;                         
    for(i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        check=false;
        do
        {
            num[i]=randrange(1,9);           

            for(j=0;j<i;j++)
            {
                if( num[i]==num[j])    // checks whether number already exists in  the array 
                    check=false;
                else
                    check=true;   
            } 
        } while(check==false);
    }
    
    // the program is working fine without the repetition  check
    // this section prints out the array elements
    for(i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        cout<<num[i]<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your duplicate checking loop has a flaw: the `check` is set to the result of checking the last pair of values, rather than the result of checking all the preceding pairs.

You need to set `check = true` before the inner loop, then proceed to verifying all items from zero to `i-1`. If the check becomes `false` at any point, stop the loop:

```
check = true;
for (j = 0 ; (check) && (j < i) ; j++) {
    check = (num[i] != num[j]);
}
```

In addition, you need to fix the `randrange`, because your current implementation returns values in range `2..11`:

```
int randrange(int low,int high)
{
    return rand()%(high-low+1)+low;     
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Just generate the numbers 1 to 9, then shuffle them randomly using [`std::random_shuffle`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/).

```
int nums[9] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
std::random_shuffle(nums, nums + 9);
```

This will leave `nums` with the numbers from 1 to 9 in random order, with no repetitions.

Comment: While this is a _much_ better algorithm, it doesn't answer the OP's question what the problem is, why the program hangs.

Answer (score 0):

Your program has a number of flaws, one of which is the range of random numbers that the `randrange` function returns. It's not 1 to 9!

The direct cause of your program (the hanging of the program) is however, that you set `check` to `false`, then perform a loop that does nothing (because the first time around, `i` is `0` and the inner loop with `j` is never performed), so `check` will always be `false`.

Check the other answers for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is probably looping. It's bit hard to read your code because of your weird indentation, but it looks like there's a logic flaw in your for loop here:

```
check=false;
do
{
    num[i]=randrange(1,9);           

    for(j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
        if( num[i]==num[j])    // checks whether number already exists in  the array 
            check=false;
        else
            check=true;   
    } 
} while(check==false);
```

You might want to remove the second `check=false;` line to do what I think you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you already might have figured out the problem by dasbinkenlight's answer

And in addition to Peter's answer, you can use `std::map` too to achieve unique random numbers:

```
std::map<int,int> m;
srand (time (NULL));   
 for(i=0;i<9;i++){
  do{ 
   j=randrange(1,9);           
  }while(m.find(j)!=m.end());

 m[j]; //insert into map, no need for value.
 num[i]=j;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>


using namespace std;

void rnd(vector<int> &v, const int n){
    for (size_t i=0;i<=n;++i){
        v.push_back(i);
    }
random_shuffle(v.begin(), v.end()); 
}
void PrintVector(const vector<int> &x){
    for (size_t i=0;i<x.size(); ++i){
        cout<<x[i]<<'\t';
    }
}

int main(){

    vector<int> a;
    rnd(a,10);
    PrintVector(a);

}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Also when answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for the green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. – Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it improves on other answers.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine for me to generate an array of random numbers from 1 to 9 without repetition

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    srand(time(0));
    int arr[10];
    for(int i=0; i<9; i++){
        arr[i] = i+1;
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    
    int j=0;
    int temp=0;
    cout << "\n\n\n-------------------------\n\n\n";
    
    for(int i=0; i<9; i++){
        j = (rand()%8)+1;
        temp = arr[i];
        arr[i]=arr[j];
        arr[j]=temp;
    }
    
    
    for(int i=0; i<9; i++){
        cout << arr[i] << "  ";
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: You have assigned the values using that of `i`. Very bad code.